# Interpreting and understanding fft plots of time series data

Tags: python, time-series, fft

I have a time series sensor data. It is for a period of 24 hours sampled every minute (so in total 1440 data points per day). I did a fft on this to see what are the dominant frequencies. But what I got is a very noisy fft and a strong peak at zero.

1. I have already subtracted the mean to remove for the DC component at bin 0. But I still get a strong peak at zero. I'm not able to figure what could be the other reason or what should I try next to remove this.
2. The graph is very different from I have usually seen online as I was learning about fft. In the sense, I'm not able to see dominant peaks like how it is usually seen. Is my fft wrong?
   Attaching code that i tried and images:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.fftpack import fft,fftfreq
import random

x = np.random.default_rng().uniform(29,32,1440).tolist()
x=np.array(x)
x=x-x.mean()
N = 1440
# sample spacing
T = 1.0 / 60
yf = fft(x)
yf_abs = abs(yf).tolist()
plt.plot(abs(yf))
plt.show()
freqs = fftfreq(len(x), 60)
plt.plot(freqs,yf_abs)
plt.show()
```

[Frequency vs amplitude](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQxI2.png)
Since I'm new to this, I'm not able to figure out where I'm wrong or interpret the results. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks! :)

Comment: Well, if you have time series data, you aren't using it.  :)  You are doing an FFT on the result of the `linspace` function, which is just going to give you a linear ramp from 29 to 32 in your case, which has no frequency component to it, aside from the very low "ramp" frequency.  Try generating some data with a sin or cos function and give it another whirl.

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to share the actual data. But I posted an image of what I get with my actual data. In general the sensor data usually varies from (29,32) and is recorded every minute. The data is generally noisy. What I'm trying to use it for is anomaly detection - in case there is any failure/process disruptions will the frequencies of the sensor data vary.

Comment: The plot that you show in your post is exactly what I get using the linear space data, which is just a line.  You should try generating date with some frequency in it for my sign or cosine function and see if you can get it to plot and makes sense

Comment: Your edit now makes the code unusable...  `np.random.default_rng()` ??